# How can I get rid of zeros, if decimal is entered it prints decimal, but if whole number is entered it prints .00?

Tags: c, decimal

This program prints overlapping of two intervals. But the problem is, if I enter, for example numbers :
1.1 -1.1 1.1 1.1, it prints out the whole number. I've tried writing %1.1f in last printf command, but it turned out to be even worse, because then, if I enter 1 2 1 1, it prints out 1.0 and 4.0. How can I get the proper print if I enter decimale or int?

```
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float a,b,c,x,derivative;
    printf("Input coefficients a, b i c: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&a,&b,&c);
    if((a<(-10)) || (a>10) || (b<(-10)) || (b>10) || (c<(-10)) || (c>10)){
        printf("Coefficients a, b i c do not belong in range of (-10,10).");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Input point x: ");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    derivative=(2*a*x)+b+(c*0);
    printf("First derivation in point x=%.f je %.f.",x,derivative);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `"%g"` [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) to display floating-point numbers in the shortest possible way:

```
printf("First derivation in point x=%g je %g",x,derivative);
```